# Can someone explain this weird ps behavior?

Tags: process, services, ps, uuid

Two issues:

1. `pf -fU <user>` not showing particular user processes while `ps -ef | grep <user>` or  `ps aux` can.
2. `pstree -p <pid>`, where pid is that particular process I mentioned above, can give output of the child processes while `ps -ef | grep <childpid>` doesn't show any.

And thisweird behavior is seen only for processes related to this particular sge service which was started using service command and not for any other processes.

```
[root@myserver ~]# ps -fU sgeadmin
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
[root@myserver ~]# ps -ef | grep sgeadmin
sgeadmin  1754     1  0 Jan21 ?        00:16:36 /ge2011.11/bin/linux-x64/sge_execd
root      4097  3982  0 18:52 pts/0    00:00:00 grep sgeadmin
sgeadmin 27248     1  0 16:59 ?        00:00:03 /ge2011.11/bin/linux-x64/sge_qmaster
[root@myserver ~]# pstree -paA 27248
sge_qmaster,27248
  |-{sge_qmaster},27255
  |-{sge_qmaster},27256
  |-{sge_qmaster},27257
  |-{sge_qmaster},27258
  |-{sge_qmaster},27263
  |-{sge_qmaster},27264
  |-{sge_qmaster},27265
  |-{sge_qmaster},27266
  |-{sge_qmaster},27267
  |-{sge_qmaster},27268
  |-{sge_qmaster},27269
  `-{sge_qmaster},27289
[root@myserver ~]# ps -ef | grep -E '27255|27256|27257|27258|27263|27264|27265|27266|27267|27268|27269|27289'
root      4274  3982  0 18:53 pts/0    00:00:00 grep -E 27255|27256|27257|27258|27263|27264|27265|27266|27267|27268|27269|27289
[root@myserver ~]#
```

So I tried starting other processes and it's working:

```
myserver @ /homes/sgeadmin : sleep 1000 &
[1] 4528
myserver @ /homes/sgeadmin : ps -fU sgeadmin
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
sgeadmin  4482  4481  0 18:57 pts/0    00:00:00 -tcsh
sgeadmin  4528  4482  0 18:57 pts/0    00:00:00 sleep 1000
sgeadmin  4529  4482  0 18:57 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -fU sgeadmin
myserver @ /homes/sgeadmin : exit
logout
[root@myserver ~]# ps -fU sgeadmin
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
sgeadmin  4528     1  0 18:57 pts/0    00:00:00 sleep 1000
[root@myserver ~]#
```

**Edit 1:**

Okay, `ps -fu <username>` gives output. It seems the difference is there in *real user id* and *effective userid*. Yes, root is the real user in this case.

But any explanation for the second issue? `pstree` showing the child processes while `ps -ef` doesn't?

**Edit 2:**

Okay, it is something to do with TGID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answers it clearly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305992/linux-threads-and-process

Here in my case, all the child processes displayed are threads and hence, can't be seen in `ps -ef` output but only pstree.